# Add column(s) to post edit page

Tags: wordpress

In the dashboard area you have the option of 1-4 columns. However when you are adding or editing a new post/page you only have the option of 1-2 columns. I would like to have be able to choose 1-3 or even 1-4 columns. I have lots of custom taxonomy that I would like to arrange more aptly by using more than 2 columns.

There is a solution, listed below and itt works on a Wordpress 3.2 installation I have but not on the current 3.4. It probably only needs a minor tweak but, I can't seem to figure it out. This is the solution from the link above...

```
'add_action( 'submitpost_box', 'third_column_edit_form' );
add_action( 'submitpage_box', 'third_column_edit_form' );
function third_column_edit_form() {
    global $post_type, $post;
    //if( 'your-type' != $post_type )
    //return;
    $side_meta_boxes2 = do_meta_boxes( $post_type, 'column3', $post );
}

add_action( 'admin_print_styles-post.php',     'third_column_css');
add_action( 'admin_print_styles-post-new.php', 'third_column_css');
function third_column_css () {
    global $post_type;
        //if( 'your-type' != $post_type )
         //     return;
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
    #side-info-column {
      width: 580px;
    }
#post-body {
  margin-right: -620px !important;
}

#post-body-content {
  margin-right: 600px !important;
}

#column3-sortables {
  width: 280px;
  float: right;
  display: block;
  min-height: 200px;
}

#side-sortables {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  min-height: 200px;
}

/* Style copied from #side-sortables */

#column3-sortables .category-tabs, #column3-sortables .category-tabs {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

#column3-sortables .category-tabs li, #column3-sortables .add-menu-item-tabs li {
  display: inline;
}

#column3-sortables .category-tabs a, #column3-sortables .add-menu-item-tabs a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#column3-sortables .category-tabs .tabs a, #column3-sortables .add-menu-item-tabs .tabs a {
  color: #333;
}
</style>
<?php
}'
```

Comment: You've mistakenly linked to a user on Stack Exchange rather than to the solution you've tried.

Comment: I took out the link because it was sort of irrelevant because the solution that works for 3.2 is listed in the question. I was just trying to give credit of where it came from.